# xcode testflight body of email

Tags: xcode, testflight

I've been handed a project started by somebody else. I assume they were disgruntled since when I do a testflight invite it has the word 'pathetic' under app description.

Where is that coming from - I can't find anything in the project itself or on itunes connect that is filling that in.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any invitation description field in your projects appstoreconnect.apple.com page? Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually in the beta description even though I wasn't making a beta.